# Is EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite embeddable in a self-contained single file application?

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a CLI tool that I would like to be fully self-contained so the user can simply run the binary directly. It is currently using .NET 5 as well as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 5.0.0.

Replicating the behaviour is very easy:

1. Create a new project with `dotnet new`
2. Add EF Core sqlite with:

   ```
   dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
   ```
3. Publish the app self-contained with:

   ```
   dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true -c Release -o publish
   ```

Now you will see the output directory will have 3 files:

```
libe_sqlite3.so
<project_name>.pdb
<project_name>
```

The two containing `<project_name>` are fine, but the libe_sqlite3.so one, which the application cannot run without, makes it not fully self-contained.

Provider and version information:

- EF Core version: 5.0.0
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Target framework: .NET 5.0
- Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#other-considerations):

> Single-file doesn't bundle native libraries by default.
>
> ...
>
> This is to ensure a good debugging experience, which requires native files to be
> excluded from the single file. There is an option to set a flag,
> `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract`, to include native libraries in
> the single file bundle, but these files will be extracted to a
> temporary directory in the client machine when the single file
> application is run.

In your case:

`dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true -c Release -o publish /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true`